# Как увеличить карту и показать маркер по центру при клике?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

У меня создана яндекс карта с множеством объектов компании, разбросанных по разным городам страны. Объекты представленны в виде маркеров с балунами. Для того чтобы клиенты могли видеть большую часть объектов сразу, на карте задан маленький масштаб (zoom:5). Я хочу по клику на маркер увеличивать карту и ставить "камеру" так, чтобы маркер, по которому я нажал, оставася в центре. Использую API версии 2.0, вот в этой [песочнице](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.0/event_rollover) я дописал такой код:

```
.add('click', function () {
    myMap.setZoom(10,{smooth:true, position:(55.755773, 37.617761),centering:true});
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. добавляем обработчик события Click для маркера, вызываем ранее созданную карту и применяем к ней метод [setZoom](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/map.xml#setZoom). В документации есть следующее про параметр centering:

> Флаг, указывающий, что по окончании плавного масштабирования позиция, заданная в options.position, должна совпасть с центром карты.

Если я правильно понял, то если включить плавное масштабирование (smooth:true), а в параметре position указать координаты конкретного маркера, по клику на этот маркер карта должна плавно увеличиться, а "кликнутый" маркер должен оказаться по центру.

Но нет, карта плавно увеличивается до нужного размера, но в центре оказывается та точка, которая была по центру карты до клика, пример на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: а правильно ли я понял документацию по setZoom()? Если да, то как правильно передать position, чтобы добиться требуемого эффекта? Если нет, то возможно ли сделать то, что я хочу другими методами Яндекс API?

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!

У `setZoom` нельзя выставить центр карты, используйте `setCenter`, второй параметр - zoom карты.

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#setCenter

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?